# Unable to find element w/ Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Let me preface this with I am a complete novice.
I am encountering the traceback `NoSuchElementException` when trying to `click` a link on a webpage.

When I inspect the element on the page I am shown this block of HTML:

```
<div class="textIcon flex flex-row items-center justify-start clickable" id="uiaas_generic_action_exportAsXls"><se-icon class="icon-small hydrated">action_download_stroke</se-icon><se-link class="hydrated">Order Status Details Report</se-link><!----><!----></div>
```

I have tried `find_element` and used `By.ID, "uiaas_generic_action_exportAsXls"`, `By.CSS_SELECTOR`, `By.CLASS_NAME, "textIcon flex flex-row items-center justify-start clickable"` and `By.LINK_TEXT, "Order Status Details Report"`, however all methods still cause the `NoSuchElementException`.

Here is my current code with trying to find the element via text having been done last:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(LandingPage)
time.sleep(5)
EmailBox = driver.find_element(By.ID,"inputEmail")
EmailBox.send_keys("testemail")
EmailBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
PwdBox = driver.find_element(By.ID,"currentPwdId")
PwdBox.send_keys("testpassword") 
PwdBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(20)
ExportBtn = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Order Status Details Report')
ExportBtn.click()
```

I have reviewed several over threads and made sure there were iframes involved and also tried to wait until the control was available, but the error has persisted. When I walk through the code with the browser not being headless, I do successfully get past the login and to the page with the control in question present.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the `<div>` by id "uiaas_generic_action_exportAsXls"?  It's the `<div>` that says it is clickable.

Comment: One of the first methods I tried was `driver.find_element(By.ID, "uiaas_generic_action_exportAsXls")` but it returned the same error.

Comment: And the error is "element not found", and not "element is not clickable"?  Do you know for sure that your username and password are being accepted?

Comment: The exact exception is "NoSuchElementException". When I walked through the code prior to making the window headless, I did get pass the login page successfully every time without it failing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I shortened it and tried to be as specific as I could, but did think the original had enough detail and the question was specific. I apologize if it was not as I am most definitely not a wordsmith.

Comment: I was here when the first version of the question was present, and it was fine. It's important that the credentials were mentioned as Selenium opens a browser that does not log the user automatically.

Comment: I added that back in and added a statement that when walking through the code, the login was successful.

Comment: You're sure the page is all present after 20 seconds?  That seems like a long time, but some web sites are slow.

Comment: I swear it was, but I will try Akash's answer below and see if the results change with the different method of waiting.

Comment: I apologize as I was pulled away. Yes it did work. Not sure what I did wrong when I previously tried the WedDriverWait method, but your solution worked and your answer has been accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that the page is not loading fast enough.

Replace `time.sleep(20)` with this:

```
# Waits 20 seconds until button is found
try:
    export_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EXP_CON.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, 'XPATH/OF/BUTTON')))
    print("Page loaded")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Page Loading Timeout...")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'XPATH/OF/BUTTON')).click()
```

To get the XPATH, go Inspect the element, right-click > copy > XPath

Edit:

Remove:

```
ExportBtn = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Order Status Details Report')
ExportBtn.click()
```